# Add script in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, google-tag-manager

I want to measure add and remove products from the cart using tag manager 
Enhanced Ecommerce.

I refered https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#cart.

How to add this script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to install an extension

This should get you started

https://www.weltpixel.com/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-tag-manager-magento-2.html